# Can I automate changing the prompt in Excel Ad-in using Python?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, win32com, excel-addins

I have performed web browser automation and other excel data analysis tasks in Python, but this time I have a requirement where I am supposed to automate Excel add inn, where I get a prompt (which comes after installing the add inn), in which I have to enter a certain number and refresh few pivots after that. Refreshing the pivot using python is possible I believe but can someone help me with the first issue. Can win32com help me with this?

Comment: What's the add-in in question?

Comment: You can try TestStack.White. It basically relies on the UIAutomation library. https://teststackwhite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/